# How to align the footer to bottom of page without using footer tag

Tags: html

I am a beginner and I have a doubt. I created this HTML table and I need to place the footer at the bottom of the page without using footer tag. Is there any way to place the footer at the bottom by using table? It will be helpful

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <h2><img src="lock.jpg"  width="80" height="30"/>Welcome to Locker</h2>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <table align="center">
          <tr>
            <td align="right">
              <h4><p> Lock name:</p></h4>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
              <h4>
                <input type="text" maxlength="8" name="lock" onkeyup="return AllowLock()"/>
              </h4>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h6 id="errfn"> </h6>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">
              <h4><p> Key:</p></h4>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
              <h4>
                <input type="text" maxlength="8" name="keys" onkeyup="return AllowKey()"/>
              </h4>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h6 id="error"></h6>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"></td>
            <td align="left">
              <input id="gobutton" type="submit" value="Go!"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id="about">About</p>
      <p id="contact">Contact us</p>
      <p id="career">Careers</p>
      <p id="press">Press</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not easily. Table-based layouts have fallen out of favour, if you were to use a more semantic structure pinning your footer to the bottom would be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/25LKc/

use a `<div><!-- footer content here --></div>` as a wrapper

with position fixed;

```
       <!-- your html here -->
   </td> 
</table>

<div class="footer"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.footer {
    background-color:orange;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS and a bit of HTML to place it, in your table tab have:

and then above it have some code for css like:

```
<script>
.table {
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0px;
}
</script>
```

This will place the table at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, for your table layout to have 100% height you need to set some CSS properties:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#my_table {
    height: 100%; 
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<table id="my_table">...</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place any element to the bottom by just adding this css to any of your classes or id's.

```
     //CSS 
{ 
position:fixed; /*Set this to absolute if you do not want it to be on bottom always*/
width:100%; 
bottom:0px; 
left:0px;
height:80px; 
}
```

//Practical Usage

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgb(216, 216, 216);
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(16, 16, 85);
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Page Content-->
    <div class="content">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Sample1</td>
                <td>Sample2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sample1</td>
                <td>Sample2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--Footer Table-->
    <table class="footer">
        <td>Footer Goes Here</td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle Example I've Created : http://jsfiddle.net/mm6qc/

Comment: it worked but i need those footer next to each other,but it overlaps with one another.what i need to do for that?

Comment: check the updated code and also refer the jsfiddle example i've created.

Comment: how to do without footer tag and css?i have to use only rowspan and colspan in table?can we able to with that?

Comment: @ashok NO !. Because without using Footer Tag, That been said, that you are not using HTML5, plus if you can't use CSS, means you can't actually achieve that as to my knowledge.